# JQuery Calculate Day Difference in 2 date textboxes

Tags: jquery, datetime

I have 2 asp.net texboxes with calendar extender. I want to find out the number of days between both dates when one of the date control is changed. how can I achieve this using jquery or javascript?

Comment: Maybe this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jquery

Comment: @Aneef, you might want to update the title of your question. It says "checkboxes" where I'm guessing you meant to say "textboxes".

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
var start = $('#start_date').val();
var end = $('#end_date').val();

// end - start returns difference in milliseconds 
var diff = new Date(end - start);

// get days
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
```

Example

```
var start = new Date("2010-04-01"),
    end   = new Date(),
    diff  = new Date(end - start),
    days  = diff/1000/60/60/24;

days; //=> 8.525845775462964
```

Comment: For me, var diff = new Date(Date.parse(to) - Date.parse(from)) works. Great answer nevertheless :)

Comment: `(Date.parse("2019-01-02") - Date.parse("2019-01-01")) / 86400000`  // => 1 day

Answer (score 12):

1) Html

```
<input type="text" id="firstDate" name="firstDate"/>
<input type="text" id="secondDate" name="secondDate"/>
```

2) Jquery

```
$("#firstDate").datepicker({

}); 
$("#secondDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        myfunc();
    }
}); 

function myfunc(){
    var start= $("#firstDate").datepicker("getDate");
    var end= $("#secondDate").datepicker("getDate");
    days = (end- start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    alert(Math.round(days));
}
```

Jsfiddle working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/AravindhGopi/tbwa1m8c/4/)

Answer (score 4):

**Hi,
This is my example of calculating the difference between two dates**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
<input class='fromdate' type="date"  />
<input class='todate' type="date" />
<div class='calculated' /><br>
<div class='minim' />  
<input class='todate' type="submit" onclick='showDays()' />

</body>
</html>
```

**This is the function that calculates the difference :**

```
function showDays(){

     var start = $('.fromdate').val();
     var end = $('.todate').val();

     var startDay = new Date(start);
     var endDay = new Date(end);
     var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

     var millisBetween = endDay.getTime() - startDay.getTime();
     var days = millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay;

      // Round down.
       alert( Math.floor(days));

}
```

**I hope I have helped you**

Comment: Math.floor(days/30)

Answer (score 2):

Number of days calculation between two dates.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.submit').on('click', function () {
            var startDate = $('.start-date').val();
            var endDate = $('.end-date').val();

            var start = new Date(startDate);
            var end = new Date(endDate);

            var diffDate = (end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
            var days = Math.round(diffDate);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it using the Math.floor() function:

```
var start = new Date($('#start').val());
var end = new Date($('#end').val());
var diff = Math.floor((end-start) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
console.log(diff);
```

You could also do it this way using the Math.round() function:

```
var start = new Date($('#start').val());
var end = new Date($('#end').val());
var diff = new Date(end - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25);
var age = Math.round(diff);
console.log(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   **This is a simple way of getting the DAYS between two dates** 
    var d1 = moment($("#StartDate").data("DateTimePicker").date());
    var d2 = moment($("#EndDate").data("DateTimePicker").date());

    var diffInDays = d2.diff(d1, 'days');

    if (diffInDays > 0)
    {
        $("#Total").val(diffInDays);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#Total").val(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var days=0;
  function myfunc(){
      var start= $("#firstDate").datepicker("getDate");
      var end= $("#secondDate").datepicker("getDate");
      days = (end- start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
      alert(Math.round(days));
  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#edate").change(function(){

   var edate = new Date($('#edate').val());
   var sdate = new Date($('#sdate').val());
   
   days = (edate- sdate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
   days=days+1;
   alert (days);
   $("#nod").val(days);
});
```

Comment: Code-only says "No need to appreciate me."

Answer (score -3):

This is a simple way of getting the DAYS between two dates

```
var nites = dateDiff(arriveDate,departDate,"D");
```

Comment: dateDiff is not a built in javascript or jquery function.