# Jquery difference between two columns table

Tags: jquery, time, diff, calculated-columns

I have a table something like this :

```
Hour 1 | Hour 2 | Difference
16:30    12:30     = ?
16:30    12:30     = ?
16:30    12:30     = ?
```

And  i want to calculate the difference between the two columns "Hour 1" and "Hour 2" with jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891325/jquery-get-the-time-in-hhmm-format-between-two-dates

Comment: and how the data is coming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr:gt(0)` means not including the top most table header row

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xbRKR/)

if you have 3rd column blank `td`

```
$('table tr:gt(0)').each(function(){
    var str_1 = $(this).find('td:nth(0)').text().split(':');
    var str_2 = $(this).find('td:nth(1)').text().split(':')
    var str_3 = (parseInt(str_1[0])-parseInt(str_2[0]))+':'+(parseInt(str_1[1])-parseInt(str_2[1]));
    $(this).find('td:nth(2)').text(str_3);
});
```

if you don't have 3rd Column blank `td` than you can append the td

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xbRKR/1)

```
$('table tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
    var str_1 = $(this).find('td:nth(0)').text().split(':');
    var str_2 = $(this).find('td:nth(1)').text().split(':')
    var str_3 = (parseInt(str_1[0]) - parseInt(str_2[0])) + ':' + (parseInt(str_1[1]) - parseInt(str_2[1]));
    $(this).append('<td>'+str_3+'</td>');
});
```

Comment: I`m looking to use : mm:ss format but if is 0 minutes i have only one ":0" instead of ":00"

Comment: @RobertCoroianu can you give an example

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to get the difference in hours i guess would be:

```
diff = (Date.parse('2000-01-01T16:30:00')-Date.parse('2000-01-01T12:30:00'))/1000/60/60;
```

To get the difference in minutes, remove the last `/60` from the above statement.

Replace `16:30` and `12:30` in the above string as needed.