# Calculate difference in days between a date pulled from an API and todays today

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to figure out how to calculate the difference in days between a date pulled through from an API and today's date.

this is the code I have used to get todays date in the format that matches date from the API:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
```

This twig code pulls the date of the API through

```
{{ job.date }}
```

What I need to work out to do and struggling with is

```
today - {{ job.date }} = Difference in Days
```

I have looked through the articles here but I have struggled to find one that I can understand.

Could this be done with twig?

Any help would be appreciated and even more so if someone could put the snippet together for me.

Comment: If you create `Date` objects from both, you can subtract them to get the difference in milliseconds. Now divide by `24 * 3600 * 1000` to get days.

Comment: @ChrisG: You should probably also round the answer to deal with the subtleties of Summer Time/Daylight Saving Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery approach with help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2609579/1573267) post

```js
//split
var todayArr = ('11/03/2019').split('/');
var startDateArr = ('10/03/2019').split('/');

//change format
var today = `${todayArr[2]}-${todayArr[1]}-${todayArr[0]}`
var startDate = `${startDateArr[2]}-${startDateArr[1]}-${startDateArr[0]}`

//calculate
var diff = new Date(Date.parse(today) - Date.parse(startDate));
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

console.log(days);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this......

```
function countDays(firstDate, secondDate) {

    var startDay = new Date(firstDate);
    var endDay = new Date(secondDate);
    var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var millisBetween = startDay.getTime() - endDay.getTime();
    var days = millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay;

    // Round down.
    alert(Math.floor(days));

}
```

Comment: You might add a `round` to this to get consistent answers in the face of Summer Time/Daylight Saving Time.  Also note that `millisBetween = startDay - endDay` will give you the same result as calling `getTime()` on each.

Answer (score 0):

If your date from api is "06/10/18" in "dd/mm/yy" format then

```
let date = "06/10/18";
let values = date.split("/");
date = new Date("20"+values[2],values[1]-1,values[0]);//months are from  0 to 11
let currDate = new Date();
let diff = currDate.getTime() - date.getTime();
diff = diff/1000; // seconds
diff = diff/60; // minutes
diff = diff/60; // hours
diff = diff/24; //days

let days = Math.round(diff);
```

Comment: You should `round` rather than `floor` (or `ceil`), as you can see when you try with 2019-03-11 and 2019-03-10.  Summer Time/Daylight Saving Time can mess with you.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottSauyet for the suggestion